How can I enable the color in nabla font in my app?
I integrated nabla font (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nabla) in my Android app, the yellow font color shows in my emulator but in my app, the color is black.
I want the yellow color to show in my app. How can I do this via code, xml or theme? Please just share code samples that could work.

AFAIK COLRv1 fonts are not supported on Android yet.

You can draw it with a solid color or a gradient but not exactly how it was designed.
